# Retrieving Data From Firebase Database Using Xamarin.Firebase.Database

Tags: xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

I am trying to figure out how to check to see if a specific key is in my Firebase Database. I am using Xamarin and the [Xamarin.Firebase.Database](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Database/) nuget package. For some reason this package is not listed on the Xamarin Compenents page like the rest of the bindings, so there are no examples that I can find specific to this package.

I want to check to see whether or not a username is already taken.

**EDIT: New code below based on the current answer.**

```
//Database instance
DatabaseReference oRoot = FirebaseDatabase.Instance.Reference.Root;
DatabaseReference oUsernamesRef = oRoot.Child("usernames");


//Username isn't taken
var userListener = new UserValueEventListener((sender, e) =>
{
    bool result = (e as UserEventArgs).value;
    if (result)
    {
        lstErrors.Add("The username you selected already exists. Please choose a different one.");
        txtUsername.Background = GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.edittext_modified_states_error);
    }
}, sUsername);

oUsernamesRef.OrderByChild("username").EqualTo(sUsername).AddListenerForSingleValueEvent(userListener);
oUsernamesRef.OrderByChild(txtUsername.Text.ToLower()).EqualTo(txtUsername.Text.ToLower()).AddListenerForSingleValueEvent(oListener);
```

**Listener:**

```
public class UserValueEventListener : Java.Lang.Object, IValueEventListener
{
    EventHandler OnChange;
    string Username;

    public UserValueEventListener(EventHandler OnChange, string Username)
    {
        this.OnChange = OnChange;
        this.Username = Username;
    }

    public void OnCancelled(DatabaseError error)
    {
        //
    }

    public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
    {
        throw new Exception("here.");
        if (OnChange != null && snapshot.Value != null && snapshot.HasChild(Username))
        {
            OnChange.Invoke(this, new UserEventArgs(true));

        }
    }
}
```

**Event**

```
public class UserEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public UserEventArgs(bool value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public bool value { get; set; }
}
```

Has anyone been able to use this package and get this working? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you have an `POJO` defined in Java (or Xamarin.Android-based C#) called `User` that contains a `Name` and `Email` property and the `Name` property is a unique key.

Calling the following adds two users, `Bar` and `Foo` to the `usernames` key:

```
var userNamesRef = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance(firebaseURL).GetReference(User.UserNameRoot);
var userSendToFirebase = new User("Bar", "bar@example.com");
var userRef = userNamesRef.Child(userSendToFirebase.Name);
userRef.SetValue(userSendToFirebase);
userSendToFirebase = new User("Foo", "foo@example.com");
userRef = userNamesRef.Child(userSendToFirebase.Name);
userRef.SetValue(userSendToFirebase);
```

You can later query for the `Bar` user by using `AddListenerForSingleValueEvent` for a one-time read of the data:

```
var userNamesRef = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance(firebaseURL).GetReference(User.UserNameRoot);
var userListener = new UserValueEventListener((sender, e) =>
{
  var userFromFirebase = (e as UserEventArgs).Value as User;
  Log.Debug(App.TAG, $"User Found!: {userFromFirebase.Name} : {userFromFirebase.Email}");
});
userNamesRef.OrderByChild("name").EqualTo("Bar").AddListenerForSingleValueEvent(userListener);
```

The `IValueEventListener`-based listener being used is:

```
public class UserValueEventListener : Java.Lang.Object, IValueEventListener
{
    EventHandler OnChange;

    public UserValueEventListener(EventHandler OnChange) => this.OnChange = OnChange;

    public void OnCancelled(DatabaseError error)
    {
        Log.Warn(App.TAG, "Failed to read value:", error.ToException());
    }

    public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
    {
        if (OnChange != null && snapshot.Value != null && snapshot.Key == User.UserNameRoot)
        {
            foreach (DataSnapshot item in snapshot.Children.ToEnumerable())
            {
                var user = item.GetValue(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(User))) as User;
                OnChange.Invoke(this, new UserEventArgs(user));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see my updated question based off of your code.

Comment: @Tristan If you are trying to determine is the user does **not** exist, in the   `IValueEventListener.OnDataChange` check if the `snapshot.Key` is the one that your are requesting and the `snapshot.ChildrenCount` is equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks. Will do, but also I don't think the listener is being fired. That exception in the OnChange function is never thrown

Comment: @Tristan If `OnChange` is never being called, then your database ref is not valid and does not match your actual firebase db.

Comment: Hmmm, no errors are being thrown. It seemed ok when I stepped through the code. I added the code I use for the reference, as well as a screenshot of the relevant portion of the db.

Comment: I think I know why.. the OrderBy and EqualTo are wrong

Comment: @Tristan ? An error would not be thrown.... Update your question with what your database looks like with multiple users in it, I think you are structuring it incorrectly...

Comment: That's possible. Updated.

Comment: @SushiHangover Sorry if i'm offtopic, but I can't find any docs of Xamarin.Firebase.Database. Have you learnt it by examples or there still exists any kind of docs?